# Sacrificing a creature I control that my opponent owns

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I were to cast [Hijack](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHijack%5d) on one of my opponent's creatures then, while that creature is under my control for the turn, I cast [Blood Divination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Divination%5d) choosing to sacrifice the creature I took from him/her, does that creature go into my graveyard (since I control the permanent), or does it go into my opponent's graveyard?

This happened recently while playing with friends and we just decided to put it in the original owner's graveyard.

Answer (score 19):

Because Magic has physical cards worth money, they go to some lengths to ensure your cards don't accidentally end up with another player. So there is NO way one of your cards ends up in another player's deck, hand or graveyard. (The other zones are shared.)

> 400.3. If an object would go to any library, graveyard, or hand other than its owner’s, it goes to its owner’s corresponding zone.

That said, things don't get that far in this situation. Sacrificing instructs you to place the card in its owner's graveyard.

> 701.16a To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. [...]

There used to be an exception when playing for ante, but that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: *Only the battlefield is shared space, and it's visible for all players.* That is incorrect. All zones except library, hand, and graveyard are shared (CR 400.1), and all zones except hand and library are public (400.2). In any case, your answer would be a better fit as a comment.

Comment: I started writing it as a comment, but then those are meant for asking clarification on the question. IMO it's just something worth putting into an answer as long as piotrek's is already there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22337)

Comment: I think this stands as a proper answer to the question; it just approaches it from a "why it's that way" instead of a rules quote.

Comment: @JoeW: this obviously isn't critique or a request for clarification.

Comment: Re "*I think this stands as a proper answer to the question*", In fact, what RemcoGerlich said is the embodiment of 400.3, which *does* answer the question. I hope they don't mind that I've smoothed the edges to produce a good answer.

Comment: Re "*this obviously isn't critique or a request for clarification.*", You're looking about this backwards. Answers have the stricter requirements: They are only for answers. It's not "This doesn't meet the exact criteria for a comment, so I'll post it as an answer." It's "This doesn't meet the exact criteria for an answer, so I'll post it as a comment.". But it's all fixed now :)

Comment: @ikegami: well, I disagree. An answer is an answer, there are no exact criteria other than answering the question, which it did -- if cards never go to the opponent's graveyard, then they also don't in his scenario. Before ikegami's edit it wasn't a particularly good answer perhaps, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Hackworth Is that only for normal mode, or is there only one command zone as well?

Comment: @Acccumulation 400.1 seems to say that Command Zone is shared as well, though this is surprising news to me.

Comment: @GendoIkari it is a little surprising, but as a public zone that isn't a pile (like the graveyard), I guess they saw no need to make them individual.  The easy way to tell if a zone is shared or not is if cards refer to "**Your** Command Zone" or ["**The** Command Zone"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[command]+[zone]||text=+[command]+[zone])

Comment: It's interesting how exile applies to this. It's the only way to cast your opponent's cards. I guess there is technically only one exile?

Answer (score 13):

You put it to its **owner's** graveyard, so in this case it's your opponent's graveyard. Magic comprehensive rules define how you sacrifice a permanent:

> **701.16a** To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. (...)